# Ajax request not returning success from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

[image]I have an onchange event that will fire an ajax request to the controller when a new dropdownlist item is selected. The controller returns a model that has new data that populates a second drop down list... This all happens in a jQuery PopUp so my goal is to repopulate a div with the new content, but the success function in Ajax is never fired... This logic should be replacing the pop up div with a view that has a new employee dropdownlist based on the role dropdownlist selection.. following this in the debugger shows me that the model is populated correctly, i don't receive any form of errors, but the dropdownlist items remain the same.

RAZOR

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Role", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleDDL, new { @class = "SimDDL", onchange = "RoleDDLChange(this)" })</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("EmpDDL", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.EmpDDL, new { @class = "SimDDL" })</td>
```

jQuery

```
function RoleDDLChange(id) {
    var SelectedRole = $('#Role').find(":selected").val();
    var url = '/Incentive/ImpersonationPopUp';
    $.ajax
        ({
            data: {
                'DDLSelection': SelectedRole
            },
            type: "get",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            //crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ImpDiaglog").load(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ImpersonationPopUp(string DDLSelection = "")
    {
        using (AppDataEntities IP = new AppDataEntities())
        {

            var Roles = IP.IncentivePayGroups.ToList()

            .Select(r => new
            {
                r.role,
                r.PayGroupID
            });
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DDLSelection))
            {
                var Emps = IP.Employees.ToList()
                .Where(E => E.IncentivePayGroup == "2" && E.UltiproActiveInactive != "Terminated" && E.UltiproActiveInactive != "Inactive")
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.UltiproEmployeeNo,
                    Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                }).OrderBy(e => e.Name);
                SelectList EmpDDL = new SelectList(Emps, "UltiproEmployeeNo", "Name");
                ImpersonationPopUp DDL = new ImpersonationPopUp(EmpDDL);
                ViewBag.RoleDDL = new SelectList(Roles, "PayGroupID", "Role");
                return PartialView(DDL);
            }
            else
            {
                var Emps = IP.Employees.ToList()
                .Where(E => E.IncentivePayGroup == DDLSelection && E.UltiproActiveInactive != "Terminated" && E.UltiproActiveInactive != "Inactive")
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.UltiproEmployeeNo,
                    Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                }).OrderBy(e => e.Name);
                SelectList EmpDDL = new SelectList(Emps, "UltiproEmployeeNo", "Name");
                ImpersonationPopUp DDL = new ImpersonationPopUp(EmpDDL);
                ViewBag.RoleDDL = new SelectList(Roles, "PayGroupID", "Role");
                return PartialView(DDL);
            }
        }
        return PartialView("~/Incentive/ImpersonationPopUp");
    }
```

Model

```
public class ImpersonationPopUp
{
    public SelectList EmpDDL {get; set;}

    public ImpersonationPopUp(SelectList EmpDDL)
    {
        this.EmpDDL = EmpDDL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try implement `complete` callback in your js part. This allows you to see some server errors if any

Comment: Thanks Aleks, im unfamiliar with this are you referring to creating a seperate function for $(document).ajaxComplete  ?

Comment: an object you passing to jQuery.ajax() method has some callbacks. Now you implement `success` function. But there also `complete` and `error` functions. Please see [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) docs

Comment: Adding the below function allowed me to explore properties of the data parameter.. There were no data errors but I did notice the DDLSelection parameter is not being passed to the controller complete: function (data) {

                }

Comment: Somewhat of a workaround, there may be a better way to do this, but I was able to use your complete function to populate my popup div instead of success. Could you please submit an answer for why my ActionResult returns Complete and not Success, and I will mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: is your ajax call returning the expected result ? 200 OK

Comment: In a way yes, the ajax request does step into the complete function, then the data attribute has a property data.responseText. I can then use this property to populate my pop up $("#ImpDiaglog").html(data.responseText);, I will note that I did not use the data: {} object for ajax because that was not sending any data but, I added the querystring to the url property and I was able to pass the parameter DDLSelection..  var url = '/Incentive/ImpersonationPopUp?DDLSelection=' + SelectedRole;